# Eye colour genetics.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

Brown eye genes is dominant vs. blue eye genes. A person inherits one factor from each parent with equal probability. If both my parents and I have brown eyes and my brother and my wife have blue eyes, what is the probability that my child has blue eyes?

Comment: I dont really know where to start with this question. If someone is able to give an idea as to how to start approaching this question then that would be great.

Comment: Could you check my answer :D I need reputation :D

Comment: Brown is $\color{#f00}{dominant}$ as compared to blue. Then, why the factors have $\color{#f00}{equal}$ probabilities ? !!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's set the recessive genes as $r$ and Dominant as $R$. If both your parents have brown eyes but you brother has blue eyes, then both of your parents have to be $Rr$. Drawing a punnet square, you have a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance of being $Rr$ and a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of being $RR$.

Your wife has $rr$ genes, as she has blue eyes. If you have $Rr$ genes, then your child has $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of having blue eyes, whereas if you have $RR$ genes, you have $0$.

Adding these cases, you get: $$\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 = \boxed{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: Oops I read "Help me start with this question" part a little late :P Well... I guess you get a free answer???

Comment: Also by "have", I mean "has a genotype of"